# Can a excel matrix be in SharePoint list?

Tags: list, connected-web-parts

I have an excel file with bunch of numbers and yes/no in a row and at the end of the row the name of the product. I like have this in a form or list in sharepoint where user will pick this items, then finally a product will be suggested for them. Does this make sense or do I need to include more info.

For example, (in excel)

```
Horsepower EngineCycle Filter SuggestProduct
100        4           Yes    Honda 1200
200        4           Yes    Honda 1500
```

so, say user picks 100, then 4, then yes, system should suggest the user Honda 1200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this in one list, though my initial thought would be to create more than one list. The key to what you want is to use connected web parts and to set the connection as a filter. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx#BM3 for more detail.

Comment: Cool thats all I needed, some guidance. Thanks Tom.